# am getting problems with char

Tags: java, netbeans, char

I am getting problems for net-beans to take a character and then say whether the person is and hr paid worker or monthly paid any help will do am getting an error for the line with char

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Infromation {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter employee num");
        int e_num=input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter employee first name");
        String e_fname=input.next();
        System.out.print("Enter employee surname");
        String e_sname=input.next();
        System.out.print("Enter employee code C,H and F");
        char e_code=input.next();
```

Comment: I don't understand what netbeans tag is doing here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
char e_code=input.next();
```

[**Scanner.next()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) returns a String.

If you wanna get the character outta Scanner.next() :

```
char e_code = input.next().charAt(0);
```

Comment: one thing if I have to do and if else if with the char how am I doing that?

Comment: if-else to check if the character is C H or F??

Comment: or lower cases of them which will be then put into a method

Comment: Character class has method to check if a character is lower or upper case refer to the API http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
char e_code=input.next().charAt(0);
                        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

instead of

`char e_code=input.next();`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Char e_code=input.next().charAt(0);
```

to get character input.

Answer (score 0):

You should creare a method to support this as it could have various problems.

```
public static char stringToChar(String value) {

  if(value == null) {
     throw new NullPointerException("stringToChar expect a not null value of argument [value]");
  }

  char[] charArray = value.toCharArray();

  if(charArray.length == 0) {
     return '\0';  // Empty 
     // or throw new IllegalStateException("stringToChar  expect a String that is not empty");
  }

  if(charArray.length == 1) {
     return charArray[0];
  }

  throw new IllegalStateException("stribtToChar expect a single Character string input:[" + value + "]");
}
```